# Strange file_get_contents behavior

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to read a file using file_get_contents(), but I get a "failed to open stream' warning when I try to do it without the absolute path.

```
<?php
    $file = 'C:\wamp\vhosts\testsite.com\a\new.txt'; //works
    $file = '\a\new.txt'; //didn't work
    $file = '/a/new.txt'; //didn't work
    echo file_get_contents($file);
```

Using WAMP, so there is no permission issues.
My question is, what is wrong with using the relative path?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$file = 'a/new.txt';` or `$file = '../a/new.txt';` depending on the script's execution location. You can also do `'/var/user/you/public_html/folder/new.txt'` and that is why your 2nd and 3rd do not work.

Comment: Relative means, relative to the folder you are in. Use `echo getcwd() . "\n";` to see the current directory you are in. If it is not `C:\wamp\vhosts\testsite.com` then you might use `chdir()` to go there or append the path to the `include_path`.

Answer (score 1):

If you start the file name with slashes that is considered an absolute path. So it will be resolved relative to the root directory. In your case `'/a/new.txt'` will be searched at `'c:/a/new.txt'`. To locate files relative to the execution directory loose the leading slash or prefix with a dot: `'a/new.txt'` or `'./a/new.txt'`